# PowerShell script runs Get-CDDrive | Set-CDDrive but won't continue after that line

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, vmware, powercli

In one of my scripts, PowerShell gets to this point, it actually does set the cd drive but then it doesn't progress from there. i have other `Write-Host` commands above the code and it looks like everything progresses and sets the cd drive, but then nothing below it will happen. Any ideas? Anyone seen this kind of issue before?

The Get/Set-CDDrive commands are coming from the VMware PowerCLI snap-in for PowerShell.

```
Get-CDDrive -VM $vmname | Set-CDDrive -IsoPath $isopath  -StartConnected:$true -Confirm:$false

Write-host "ISO attached successfully"

Write-host "[INFO] VM $($vmname) deployed"
```

Comment: Why is there white-space between the `-` and `Confirm` ?

Comment: there isn't a space between - and confirm

Comment: You probably fail to run the script. Poweshell doesn't just stop if it fails, it continues while raising exceptions. How do you try to launch that script?